# How to upload video recorded with MediaRecorder API using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api

I am working on a video recording task using MediaRecorder API. As from frontend I can start the webcam, record video, play the recorded video and download the video.
[image]

But when I try to upload the video to php server, it's not at all working. I don't really understand why it is happening, I also tried using so many methods but none of it is working. Please check the code attatched below.

JS:-

```
let mediaRecorder
let recordedBlobs

const errorMsgElement = document.querySelector('span#errorMsg');
const recordedVideo = document.querySelector('video#recorded');
const recordButton = document.querySelector('button#record');
const playButton = document.querySelector('button#play');
const downloadButton = document.querySelector('button#download');

document.querySelector("button#start").addEventListener("click", async function() {
    const hasEchoCancellation = document.querySelector("#echoCancellation").checked

    const constraints = {
        audio: {
            echoCancellation:{
                exact: hasEchoCancellation
            }
        },
        video: {
            width: 1280,
            height: 720
        }
    }

    await init(constraints)
})

async function init(constraints) {
    try {
        const stream  = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        handleSuccess(stream)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

function handleSuccess(stream) {
    recordButton.disabled = false

    window.stream = stream

    const gumVideo = document.querySelector("video#gum")

    gumVideo.srcObject = stream
}

recordButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(recordButton.textContent === "Record") {
        startRecording()
    } else {
        stopRecording()
        recordButton.textContent = 'Record'
        playButton.disabled = false
        downloadButton.disabled = false
    }
})

function startRecording() {
    recordedBlobs = []

    let options = {
        mimeType: "video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus"
    }

    try {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

    recordButton.textContent = "Stop Recording"
    playButton.disabled = true
    downloadButton.disabled = true

    mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
        console.log('Recording Stopped')
    }
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable
    mediaRecorder.start()
}

function handleDataAvailable(event) {
    if(event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        recordedBlobs.push(event.data)
    }
}

function stopRecording() {
    mediaRecorder.stop()
}

playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {
        type: 'video/webm'
    })
    var file = new File([superBuffer], 'test.webm')
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer)
    // var video = blobToFile(superBuffer, 'test.webm')
    sendToServer(file)
    recordedVideo.src = null
    recordedVideo.srcObject = null
    recordedVideo.src = url
    recordedVideo.controls = true
    recordedVideo.play()
})

downloadButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/mp4'});
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'test.mp4';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 100);
});

function sendToServer(file) {
    let url = 'send.php'
    let headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("file", file)
    axios.post(url, formData, headers)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response)
        })
}

function blobToFile(theBlob, fileName){
    //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below which we will add
    theBlob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    theBlob.name = fileName;
    return theBlob;
}
```

PHP:-

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . 'test.webm';
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "File uploaded successfully";
} else {
    echo "File not uploaded";
}
print_r($_FILES['file']['error']);
```

No matter how much I tried, I can't figure out why it is not working. It is showing that "File not uploaded" like it can't read the file from tmp_name. Please help me fix the problem.
Any help on this problem will be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What debugging have you tried? Anything on your devtools console?  Do you see the POST on the network tab of devtools, and if you inspect it do you see the file etc you expect?  What is `$target_dir`, and does your web server have write perms there? Have you added debugging to check what `$_FILES` looks like? What is `$_FILES['file']['error']`?  There's lots of [sample code in the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for tracing problems, have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah I tried that too. I tried to return $_FILES array as the response and printed it in dev console. It showed there is a file, but didn't worked on upload.